# How to "disable" comments detection when parsing a file with CSVParser / CSVStrategy (Apache Commons)

Tags: java, parsing, csv, comments, apache-commons

In a Java program, I need to parse a CSV file. Nothing extremely unusual there.
The implementation I use is Apache Commons's [CSVParser](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html), witch now uses a [CSVStrategy](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVStrategy.html) as parameter to define the CSV dialect.

The thing is, I need to get rid of the option to look for comments in the input file. The input file is supposed to have no comments, and every character (except `;`, of course) should be kept and be considered meaningful. Especially, the standard `#` character should not be a comment.

Here is the code I use so far (which cause problems with `#`, as expected) :

```
fRead = new FileReader(someFilePath);
data = new CSVParser(fRead, new CSVStrategy(';', '"', '#')).getAllValues();
```

The thrid argument of CSVStrategy's constructor is a `char`, so it cannot be `null`.

Something interesting is the presence of the static char `COMMENTS_DISABLED` and method `isCommentingDisabled()` in CSVStrategy, yet no setter for something similar.

There is a constructor of CSVParser which takes only the reader and a delimiter char as parameters, and no CSVStrategy, but it's deprecated. So I figure there is a way to achieve similar functionality with the CSVStrategy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By quickly looking at the [source code](http://commons-csv.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.1-SNAPSHOTplus-psvn678580/CSVStrategy_8java-source.html), it seems that you can use the CSVStrategy constructor like this :

```
data = new CSVParser(fRead, new CSVStrategy(';', '"', CSVStrategy.COMMENTS_DISABLED)).getAllValues();
```

Comment: I thought it was meant to be used that way. Thing is, what is `COMMENTS_DISABLED` ? In the end, doesn't that mean another character will be interpreted as the beginning of comments, but as an added bonus, I will have no idea which character it is ?

Comment: I think that comments will not be skipped, but interpreted as normal tokens.

Comment: I wanted a more detailed answer about what was the "COMMENTS_DISABLED" char before using it (as I don't want to be unable to parse another character hidden between that name). Turns out `CSVStrategy.COMMENTS_DISABLED` is the Little-Endian BOM in UTF-16. It still is a character, but indeed an acceptable one to indicate comments, so this will work.

Comment: From the [comments](http://commons-csv.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.1-SNAPSHOTplus-psvn678580/CSVStrategy_8java-source.html) // -2 is used to signal disabled, because it won't be confused with an EOF signal (-1), and because \ufffe in UTF-16 would be encoded as two chars (using surrogates) and thus there should never be a collision with a real text char.